# Real analysis and Lhopitals rule

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$ and let $c \in (a,b) $. Suppose that $f$ and $f^{'}$ are non-zero on a deleted neighborhood of $c$ , but $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c}f(x) = 0.$$ Find $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c} |{f(x)}^{|f(x)|}.$$ How would I apply l'Hopital's rule in that question? I just don't know where to start, any hints please?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\ell(t)=t\,\log t$ for $t\gt0$. When $t\to0^+$, $\ell(t)\to0$. Furthermore, for every $x$ such that $f(x)\ne0$,
$$
|f(x)|^{|f(x)|}=\exp(\ell(|f(x)|)),
$$
hence, if $f(x)\to0$ with $f(x)\ne0$ in a neighborhood of $c$, then $\ell(|f(x)|)\to0$ when $x\to c$, $x\ne c$, and $\exp(\ell(|f(x)|))\to1$, that is, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow c} |{f(x)}^{|f(x)|}=1.$$
Note that the differentiability hypothesis is superfluous and that, even assuming differentiability, L'Hopital is not the most direct approach.